# How to define a weighted cone?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-colimits, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $F : I \to C$ be a diagram in $C$, and $N$ an object of $C$. A cone from $N$ to $F$ is a family of morphism $P_X : N \to F(X)$ such that for every morphism $f : i1 \to i2$ in $I$, $F(f) \circ P_X = P_Y$. And the limit of $F$ is the universal cone.

If $C$ is now a $Cat$-enriched category and $W : I \to Cat$ is given as a weight, is there a notion of $W$-weighted cone such that a $W$-weighted limit is a universal $W$-weighted cone? If yes, how do you define such a $W$-weighted cone? And what does it mean for it to be universal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a cone from $N$ to $F$ is a natural transformation from the constant functor $\Delta N$ to $F$. A cone is universal if it represents the functor $[I,C](\Delta -,F) : C^\text{op} \to \textbf{Set}$, i.e. if it induces isomorphisms $$C(X,N) \cong [I,C](\Delta X,F)$$ for all objects $X$ of $C$. Note that there is a natural isomorphism $$[I,C](\Delta X,F) \cong [I,\textbf{Set}](\Delta 1, C(X,F-)),$$ so we can see ordinary (universal) cones as $\textbf{Set}$-enriched $\Delta 1$-weighted (universal) cones.

Now in the 2-categorical context, let $\hat{F}$ denote the 2-functor $C^\text{op} \to [I,\textbf{Cat}]$ with $\hat{F}X = C(X,F-)$.
A $W$-weighted cone from $N$ to $F$ is then a 2-natural transformation $W \to \hat{F}N$, and such a cone is universal if it represents the 2-functor $[I,\textbf{Cat}](W,\hat{F}-) : C^\text{op} \to \textbf{Cat}$, i.e. if it induces isomorphisms of categories $$C(X,N) \cong [I,\textbf{Cat}](W,C(X,F-))$$ for all objects $X$ of $C$. This defines the universal property of the $W$-weighted limit of $F$.

Re your comment: 
A 2-natural transformation $\theta : F\to G : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is given by a family of 1-morphisms $\theta_A : FA \to GA$ of $\mathcal{B}$, indexed by the objects A of $\mathcal{A}$, such that the diagram of functors

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{A}(A,B) @>F>> \mathcal{B}(FA,FB)\\
@VGVV @VV\mathcal{B}(1,\theta_B)V\\
\mathcal{B}(GA,GB) @>>\mathcal{B}(\theta_A,1)> \mathcal{B}(FA,GB)
\end{CD}$$

commutes for all objects $A,B$ of $\mathcal{A}$. This amounts to the usual naturality condition, plus an extra condition that for every 2-cell $\alpha : f \to g : A \to B$ of $\mathcal{A}$, we have $$\theta_B \circ F\alpha = G\alpha \circ \theta_A,$$ where $\circ$ denotes horizontal composition (''whiskering'' in this case) in $\mathcal{B}$.

Weighted limits and enriched natural transformations are elementary definitions of enriched category theory, which may be found in the standard reference on the subject, Kelly's book [*Basic concepts of enriched category theory*](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html).

Comment: I see indeed that the commutative diagram $F(f) \circ P_X = P_Y$ is the naturality of the cone. Your answer would be complete if you could spell out the commutative diagram coming from the 2-naturality of the weighted cone.

Comment: @Bob, I have spelled out the definition of 2-natural transformation.

Comment: My point was that I expect as an answer an elementary definition of a weighted cone similar to the elementary definition of a cone in my question. Although, I could find the definition of a 2-natural transformation in Borceux's book, I still have a hard time unfolding everything to arrive at an elementary definition of a weighted cone.

Comment: @Bob What is the difficulty? A $W$-weighted cone from $N$ to $F$ is precisely a 2-natural transformation $W \to \hat{F}N : I \to \textbf{Cat}.$ Just substitute these specific 2-functors and 2-categories for the arbitrary ones in the definition of 2-natural transformation and you have your answer.